# Format cursom days/hours into 'work hours and days'

Tags: php, time, format, date

I'm making a quoting system and I need a way to turn

`1 days, 15 hours` into `2 days, 7 hours` where each day contains 8 hours.

I have access to both the days and hours variables so a function could be

```
function formatWorkHours($days, $hours){

}
```

Can anyone help me with this please? Other examples could be `1 days, 26 hours`.

Thanks!

Comment: Should the days also be converted? In that case the correct result for `1 days, 15 hours` regular time is equal to `4 days, 7 hours` in work time.

Comment: I'm sorry, 1 days, 15 hours is only 2 days 7 hours? Not sure where you got 4 days from.

Comment: Well, if you consider that a day in normal time is 24 hours, a single day equates to 3 workdays. But I guess this is not the case in your problem as you've accepted the answer.

Comment: ah right, i get what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function formatWorkHours($days, $hours){
    $days += floor( $hours / 8 );
    $hours = $hours % 8;
    echo "$days days, $hours hours";
}

formatWorkHours( 1, 15 ); //echoes "2 days, 7 hours"
formatWorkHours( 1, 26 ); //echoes "4 days, 2 hours"
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Also, i can see how this works as well. Thank you.